# Automapper and validate configuration with DDD

Tags: c#, automapper

I have simple domain model in DDD approach so only way to create instance is use constructor.

```
public CashCaseDifference(
        double amount,
        double originalAmount,
        double originalFcyAmount,
        CashCaseDifferenceCurrency currency,
        CashCaseDifferenceSource source,
        CashCaseDifferenceType type)
    {
        this.Amount = amount;
        this.OriginalAmount = originalAmount;
        this.OriginalFcyAmount = originalFcyAmount;
        this.Currency = currency;
        this.Source = source;
        this.Type = type;
    }
```

And I have problem when I'am trying to unit test the configuration.

Mapping profile:

```
this.CreateMap<CashCaseOut, CashCaseDifference>()
                .ConstructUsing(source => new CashCaseDifference(
                    source.Amount.GetValueOrDefault(),
                    source.OriginalAmount.GetValueOrDefault(),
                    source.OriginalFcyAmount.GetValueOrDefault(),
                    (CashCaseDifferenceCurrency) source.Currency.GetValueOrDefault(),
                    (CashCaseDifferenceSource) source.SourceOfDifference.GetValueOrDefault(),
                    (CashCaseDifferenceType) source.Type.GetValueOrDefault()));
```

And my unit test method:

```
  Mapper.Initialize(
            cfg => { cfg.AddProfile(new CashCaseOutToCashCaseDifference()); });
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(););
```

It return error that properties are not mapped:

```
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
```

"Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters"

```
Unmapped properties: Source
```

## Edit:

Construction do not work as well.

```
      Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new CashCaseOutToCashCaseDifference());
        });
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

  public CashCaseOutToCashCaseDifference()
    {
        this.CreateMap<
                CashDiffMS.Client.Models.CashCaseOut,
                Core.CashCases.Domain.Differences.CashCaseDifference>()
            .ForCtorParam("amount", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Amount))
            .ForCtorParam("originalAmount", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OriginalAmount))
            .ForCtorParam("originalFcyAmount", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OriginalFcyAmount))
            .ForCtorParam("currency", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Currency))
            .ForCtorParam("source", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SourceOfDifference))
            .ForCtorParam("type", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Type));
    }

public CashCaseDifference(
        double amount,
        double originalAmount,
        double originalFcyAmount,
        CashCaseDifferenceCurrency currency,
        CashCaseDifferenceSource source,
        CashCaseDifferenceType type)
    {
        this.Amount = amount;
        this.OriginalAmount = originalAmount;
        this.OriginalFcyAmount = originalFcyAmount;
        this.Currency = currency;
        this.Source = source;
        this.Type = type;
    }
```

Result is that same: `Unmapped properties: Source`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're mapping by hand. You should let AM do it. The docs are [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Construction).

Comment: That should work. A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.